# How to change meta key (leader key M-m/Alt-M) in spacemacs? (emacs, ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

Assuming question applies also to emacs 'classic'/default. Spacemacs being specific Emacs configuration. Possibly relevant fact for eventual differences between Emacs default and spacemacs.

I know I can do something like this in my .spacemacs config

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-z") 'meta)
```

but this does not work.

Question is how I can change M-m or Alt-m (which is as far as I understand the default meta command key, often reffered as SPC) to be, for example, Alt-z or in emacs speech M-z.

some suggest using Alt-space (but that one is reserved by Ubuntu for window operations)

1. problem - is M-z correct syntax ?
2. if that is ok, what is actual emacs command to be executed (is it 'meta) ?
3. is it possible at all to redefine main meta keys using this approach?

Reason for this question is ergonomic.